# python gathering return value of multiple function and validate input against all function at one non-main function

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I am looking for solution where I can make sure that input value tested  against each function and returned for all error case.

Here is my code.

```
def func_a(value):
   do something
   return

def func_b(value):
    do something
    return

def func_c(value):
    do something
    return

def final(value):
    A=def_a(value)
    B=def_b(value)
    C=def_c(value)
    if A != foo:
      return A
    elif B != foo:
      return B
    elif C != foo:
      return C
    else:
       return'Success'

    main()

       print final(value)
```

Problem:

I passing one file as a value where each line should be tested against certain test. Now if there is a issue in line which matches to def_a(), the def_a() will be executed but that line did not tested against remaining functions(fund_b, fund_c) due to if loop in def final().

Question:

Is there a way , I can craft a def final() such a way that each line tested for all functions and if that line match with more than one function then both conditions will be executed?

Comment: Please use proper formatting.

Comment: It is very unclear what you mean by "each line should be tested against a certain test". In your pseudocode, you're calling `def_a`, `def_b` and `def_c` unconditionally, then later picking which of their return values to return based on their values. That might make sense, but it's not clear what you really want to do. Can you show some real, runnable code and give an example input that doesn't behave the way you want?

Comment: Basically each line in file has some pattern that match either def a b or c and the def final() collected result from all there functions and return to main function. The issue is coming when one line has a pattern which matches to def_a and def_b and in def final() function its not retiring the value for def_b() since it already matched to def_a().

Answer (score 0):

Store the function results in a dictionary and return it as needed:

```
def final(value):
    result = {'A':def_a(value),
              'B':def_b(value),
              'C':def_c(value)}
    if any(item != foo for item in result.values()):
      return result
    else:
       return'Success'
```